# Table of Contents links in Kindle no longer work

Tags: kindle

The links for Table of Contents in my kindle no longer workers. It doesn't take me to the location of the page anymore. Instead, whenever I click on it, the Oxford Dictionary pops up.

Any ideas why?

Comment: have you edited the book's source code or is this a recent development for a book that has remained in your library the entire time and not been edited?

Comment: You'll have to provide some more information to get a useful response. Can you include some of the relevant code?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I once was able to swipe in from the left margin to access another part of the book that I was reading. It is very helpful for cookbooks! Now I have to continue to swipe to beginning or end to change my location. It is very discouraging since it was there in the past.

Comment: I am having the same m e problem, specifically with Kindle version Bibles. I don't happen to know page numbers of different books of the Bible. I do; however, know the 66 book names, which is exactly how a Bible is navigated. I would like to have my feature restored. Table of contents may not matter with a Joel C Rosenberg book, but it is critical to Bible contents.